# Python selenium create webdriver using portable firefox

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I have downloaded a portable Firefox and trying to use it in my code but haven't had any success.

Here's the code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/installed firefox binary')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Here's the exception I am getting:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: copy geckodriver in /usr/local/bin

Comment: I passed `executable_path=/path/to/geckodriver` as second argument to `webdriver.Firefox` but still got WebDriver exception.

Comment: Looks like it might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path